# How to completely download Anaconda Cloud bz2 files and dependencies for offline package installation?

Tags: package, conda

I want to install a Conda package in offline mode. I have tried to download bz2 files in other PC using this command:

```bash
conda install packagename --download-only
```

and moved the .bz2 file onto the offline PC and installed it using

```bash
conda install *.bz2
```

This works for a simple package. But for complex packages like `atoti` with a lot of dependencies, it seems that it can't be completely installed as other packages in offline PC are not compatible with `atoti`.

Is there any way to download all packages .bz2 files at once?

Comment: I would note that once you have the files downloaded, copy all of them to the `pkgs` directory of the Conda installation, and then simply run `conda install atoti`, i.e., don't specify the `.tar.bz2` files directly.

Comment: `conda-pack` might also be an alternative in case you already know exactly which packages you need in your env.